# Connect a hundred SIM800L's to Arduino (or any other board)

Tags: arduino-uno

Is there a way to connect one hundred SIM800L's to Arduino? Essentially I want to be able to communicate with any of them that I want. If Arduino isn't capable of doing this, what do you suggest, so I could connect to and control 100 SIM cards?

Thanks for your help in advance!

R.

Comment: Wow, 100 is much. Maybe with a series of multiplexer modules (only talking to one at a time). But why do you need to talk to 100 SIM800L? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It is likely the additional hardware needed will exceed that of most Arduino platforms.  That is, while using an Arduino Uno may work, it would be like building a race car from a go cart.

Comment: @chrisl That's for a project I am creating a PoC for. Ideally I want to be able to talk to an unlimited number of SIMs for making calls, sending texts etc. Can you please provide a link or example for using "multiplexer modules" ?

Comment: @st2000 That's fair do's. It doesn't really have to be an Arduino. I just don't know how to connect a SIM800L to a Desktop computer for example, let alone connecting hundreds of them. If money wasn't an object (within reason), what hardwares would you propose to achieve this? I'm a software engineer so coding it up is I guess the easier part, as long as it's possible to talk to the modules.

Comment: You need to think modular. Forget one central "brain" with hundreds of modems connected to it - think lots of small brains with only a few modems on each one, all communicating to a central controller over some other transmission medium (ethernet?)

Comment: @Majenko Could a SIM800L be connected to a normal desktop motherboard? Would that be through a USB-to-Serial interface? If so, are there these interfaces that provide, say 50 serial output pins so I could connect 50 SIM800L's?

Comment: @jsotola It's going to be sending lots of texts from different numbers.

Comment: @jsotola I highly doubt they will work without a SIM card active somewhere in the network. Also the networks I've been on don't support that feature. Also I want to be able to receive texts too. Maybe add a phone call feature later on too. So no, I will need to physically connect my 100 sim cards somewhere.

Comment: now it is clear what you are trying to do .... your question above is still unclear ... please edit the question to include all of the information that you put in comments, then delete the comments

Answer (score 1):

You left unclear, what your exact requirements are. So the answer will be as general as your question. The SIM800L uses the Serial interface (UART). So the point is to connect to 100 different serial interfaces.

If it is ok to talk to each SIM800L sequentially (only one at a time), you can use a series of multiplexers. A multiplexer chip connects one pin to one of multiple pins (called channels here). Depending on the used chip, the channel can be selected in different ways. The standard way is with simple digital input pins, that construct a binary number. So for 8 channels you need 3 input pins (`2^3`). Other ways are through communication interfaces like SPI or I2C.

Normally a multiplexer has only 8 channels, though you can also find once with more, but I don't think there are multiplexers with 100 channels. So you could next the multiplexers. If you put another multiplexer on every channel of the first multiplexer, you get `8*8 = 64` channels with 9 multiplexers in total. Add some more multiplexers on the next level and you will get to over 100 channels. Then you need 2 of these multiplexer trees to multiplex both serial lines (TX and RC). Since that are a lot of multiplexers and thus a lot of inputs to choose the correct channels, you could use multiplexers with SPI or I2C interface. The first would require 1 digital output pin of the Arduino per multiplexer as slave select pin, the latter would require either a multiplexer type, that can as many different I2C addresses as multiplexers in your system, or a bit more complex programming and also 1 pin per multiplexer to change the address of the chip to configure. How to use these multiplexers with Arduino depends on the used chip. You should refer to it's datasheet.

As you now see, connecting one single Arduino to 100 serial interfaces it a complex task. Depending on your actual requirements and goals in your "PoC project", it might be a better way to follow Majenkos advice and build it more modular with multiple Arduinos/microcontrollers.

Comment: Thanks, I understood what those multiplexers do. I assume the multiplexers switching between pins would have a delay. That, and the fact I wouldn't be able to for example ask 10 SIM800L's to each do something (multithreading if you like), makes it a not so good option. Agreed Majenkos' solution sounds better.